# What does this equal to???

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 6 p. 390:

[image: img]

There seems to be something missing at the place underlined in red.  Could this be `∅` (null symbol)?

Comment: it sure looks that way

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it **has** to be $\varnothing$, as the text above explicitly states that the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. $\varnothing$ is a special character and may have failed to render in the final document, or it may be a slip of the mind.

Comment: Thank you!  I was hesitant and need confirmations.